# Open Roberta - what is the meaning of the "drive" block without specifying the distance?

Tags: roberta

I made a simple program(image) using Open Roberta EV3 with only 2 instructions (start and drive forwards).
[image: Simple program]

Question: is the drive forwards block without any specified distance equivalent to drive forwards for a distance of 1 cm? The test I made suggests this is the case but the documentation suggests otherwise: https://lab.open-roberta.org/help/progHelp_ev3_en.html

> »drive« With the »drive« block you can program the direction and also
> the speed (velocity) of your robot. **Your robot moves until it is
> stopped or another block specifies new driving parameters**. The driving
> speed can be set in the field »speed«.

Documentation suggests that the movement should be continuous until something happens meaning:

- Some blockage occurs, eg car encounters a rock.
- Or "another block specifies new driving parameters", this is even more confusing, how could another block specify new driving parameters? I just made my first contact with Roberta and it seems to me that is not multithreading so at any time a single instruction can be executed, I really can't see how another block can stop my current drive.